# Centering issue with image overlay

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have my script adding the image src to the overlay's image and working correctly in that sense. The problem is when I create my variable `imgH` to apply as a value for `margin-top`. I have it grabbing the image's height and divide in into half.

I was having the problem when a value ended with .5 so I used `safeInt = Math.floor(iH),` to remove any decimal for the value.

On my portfolio the centering is very random or applies 0 to the overlay. I can not figure out what is not allowing the variable to be correct to center the image.

I am a slightly experienced with jquery so I apologize if this is a novice mistake.

Here is the jQuery:

```
function imgOverlay() {
    $('.codeCont img').on('click', function() {
        var imgData = $(this).attr('data');

        $('.overlay').fadeIn().find('img').attr('src', imgData);

        if ($('.overlay img').attr('src') === 'images/vec-3.jpg') {
            $('.overlay').addClass('imgLong');
        }
        else {
            $('.overlay').removeClass('imgLong');
        }

        $('.close').on('click', function() {
            $('.overlay').fadeOut();
        });

        var iH = $('.overlay img').height()/2,
            safeInt = Math.floor(iH),
            imgH = "-" + safeInt + 'px';

        $('.overlay').css({
            'margin-top' : imgH
        });
    });
}

imgOverlay();
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/gV7Gh/) - If you go from left to right through the images you will see random behaviors on the `margin-top`.

Here is a [direct link to the site](http://jpowell43.mydevryportfolio.com/Port-2:14/) to see the clearest problem.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why are you trying to set the margin to half the height of the overlay?

Comment: I am trying to grab the height of the overlay's image and then divide it into half. Then apply that number to the overlay as a negative `margin-top` to center the image.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the height of your image before it is loaded on the page. You need to perform the calculation and setting the margin top in a load handler for the image such as

```
function imgOverlay() {
   ...
   $('.overlay img').load(overlayLoad);
}

function overlayLoad()
{
   var iH = $('.overlay img').height()/2,
            safeInt = Math.floor(iH),
            imgH = "-" + safeInt + 'px';

    $('.overlay').css({
      'margin-top' : imgH
    });
}
```